# ph-schematron: namespace prefix error after compiling schematron to xslt using ph-sch2xslt-maven-plugin

Tags: xslt, schematron

I am using ph-sch2xslt-maven-plugin 3.0.0 to compile the following simple schematron to xslt:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
  <ns prefix="m" uri="http://www.ociweb.com/movies"/>
  <pattern name="all">
    <rule context="m:actor">
      <report test="@role=preceding-sibling::m:actor/@role"
          diagnostics="duplicateActorRole">
        Duplicate role!
      </report>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
  <diagnostics>
    <diagnostic id="duplicateActorRole">
      More than one actor plays the role<value-of select="@role"/>.
      A duplicate is named<value-of select="@name"/>.
    </diagnostic>
  </diagnostics>
</schema>
```

The plugin compiles the schematron into an xslt file.   However, attempting to use the compiled xslt file results in an "Undeclared namespace prefix" error.

Using ph-schematron 3.0.0, the following snippet:

```
final ISchematronResource isr = schematronResourceXSLT.fromFile(aSchematronFile);
if (!isr.isValidSchematron ())
   throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid Schematron!");
```

Produces this:

```
[main] INFO com.helger.schematron.xslt.SchematronResourceXSLTCache - Compiling XSLT instance [file=/opt/temp/phschematron/schematron-model/src/main/resources/xslt/movies.xslt]
[main] ERROR com.helger.commons.xml.transform.LoggingTransformErrorListener - [fatal_error] Transformation fatal error (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Undeclared namespace prefix {m})
[main] ERROR com.helger.commons.xml.transform.LoggingTransformErrorListener - [fatal_error] Transformation fatal error (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Undeclared namespace prefix {m})
[main] ERROR com.helger.schematron.xslt.SchematronProviderXSLTPrebuild - XSLT read/compilation error for [file=/opt/temp/phschematron/schematron-model/src/main/resources/xslt/movies.xslt]
```

When using the schematron directly, it works and the `isValidSchematron()` returns true:

```
final ISchematronResource aResPure = SchematronResourcePure.fromFile(aSchematronFile);
if (!aResPure.isValidSchematron ())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid Schematron!");
```

Can someone please explain what is causing the namespace error?

Comment: I took your schematron file, changed `<pattern name="all" >`  to `<pattern id="all" >` (as the name attribute is not allowed) and used oXygen (sorry, no Maven handy) to generate the XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, both worked. It added the namespace prefix `m` in the appropriate place. Perhaps a bug? You can fix it by adding the `m` namespace to the root of the resulting XSLT by hand (use a post-process XSLT with this XSLT as input to add it).

Comment: Abel - thanks for the feedback.  I think there's a bug in the ph-sch2xslt-maven-plugin as it ignores the namespace prefix element.

Comment: Well, [since it is open source](https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron), have you tried checking the rules on it processing `ns` nodes? Or report it as a bug, or if you can fix it, suggest a fix?

Comment: The problem is  that you are using the wrong class. `SchematronResourceXSLT` is only to be used, if you have the pre-converted file. If you have the Schematron XML use `SchematronResourceSCH` instead. I just check with the current 4.0.1-SNAPSHOT and the Schematron is valid!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [issue](https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron/issues/25) with ph-schematron and has been fixed in 4.0.1, released on 05-Jul-2016.

Comment: Thanks to your help Bae :)